# Prove there exists no function in the complex plane, excluding the origin, such that $f(zw)=f(z)f(w)$ and $(f(z))^2=z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that there does not exist a function $f: C\rightarrow C$, excluding the origin, with the following two properties:

$f(zw)=f(z)f(w)$ for all $z,w$ $\in C$ and  $(f(z))^2=z$ for all $z$ $\in C$

My attempt:

Assume on the contrary that such a function exists. The existence of this function leads to the implication that

$f(zw)=f(z)f(w)$  implies  $(f(z))^2=f(z)f(z)=f(zz)=f(z^2)=z$

I consider the identity map such that
$f(zw)=zw$ and show that the implication does not hold for all $z$. My question is whether the the counterexample using the identity map is valid.

Answer (score 7):

No, that's just saying that the identity map is not a solution.

EDIT: 
$f(1) = f((-1)^2) = f(-1)^2 = -1$, but also ...

Comment: Good point.  Oh, there's a much simpler argument...

Comment: I wish you would have shared it once you found it!

Comment: ... $f(1) = f(1^2) = f(1)^2 = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for posting that, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

No; if $f(z)=z^2$ , then we must have $f(z)=e^{2log(f(z))}$ for some choice of $logz$ . But no log can be defined in a region that winds around $0$. IOW, for a square root (of $f(z)$ ) to exist, $f(z)$ cannot wind around the origin.

Comment: The fact that $f(z)$ cannot wind around the origin is due to $\log(z)$ being a multivalued function and thus we define a principal branch cut. This implies that the square root is not a continuous function. However, the problem makes no statement concerning the continuity of $f(x)$ so I am not sure if this would answer the problem.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the problem is asking to show that any function $f : z \mapsto $ some choice of $\sqrt{z}$ is never multiplicative. In that case saying it has the form $e^{1/2 \log(z)}$ loses a lot of generality

Comment: @tfw: but, how else can one define $\sqrz$, even if not continuous; AFAIK, the only way to define $z^a$ for $a$ non-integer is using some branch of log?

Comment: @DBFdalwayse At any point taking some choice of $\sqrt{z}$. Maybe at $1$ we take $f(1) = 1$ but at $1+\epsilon$, $f(1+\epsilon) = -\sqrt{1+\epsilon}$. If $f$ is not continuous then we can do this.